# MySQL Workbench do not use all the cpu cores

Tags: mysql, performance, ubuntu, cpu, workbench

I have a little problem with my Workbench on Ubuntu 16.04.
I noticed while I am copying a multiple csv-row on a table (not INSERT), workbench became grey and then stack for a while, usually more the 10/15 min.
I know that there are other way to import csv etc... but the problem is that while he is copying the data in the table, just to show to myself how beautifull is gonna be the table after the insert, the CPU1 goes straigth to 100% and all the other cpu stays around 5% to 10% and then after a while it switch to another cpu and same story happened. Cause is not mysql doing the job, but the software, why the software doesn't use all 4 core to get a boost?
I have an Intel® Core™ i7-3537U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 4 and 8GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

No.

A single connection in MySQL will use only a single CPU core.

If you could determine what underlying SQL is involved, perhaps we could help you find a more efficient way to do the task.

Comment: But in that moment mysql is not used, cause i haven't sent any query to the DB

Comment: @gabry010 - "he is copying the data in the table" -- How is this done?  For that matter, what do you mean?  "reading the data", "copying the data from one tale to another", "copying the data to the screen", "using a pencil to copy the data"???